# Variable not defined uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

My HTML and CSS are working as expected, but I got stuck with JavaScript for a 'Scroll to Top' button and a promo bar scripts:

```js
/* app.js */
var app = (function() {
    /* Properties */
    var websiteName = "PetShop";
    /* Methods */
    return {
        getWebsiteName: function() {
            return websiteName;
        }
    }
})();

/* home.js */
function HomeIndex() {
    /* Properties */
    const heightFromTop = 300;
    /* Methods */
    this.initialiseScrollToTopButton = function() {
        /* Windows Scroll Event Handler */
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            /* Show of Hide Scroll Event to Top Button based on scroll distance */
            var verticalHeight = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (verticalHeight > heightFromTop) {
                $("#scrollToTop").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $("#scrollToTop").fadeOut();
            }
        });
        /* Scroll to Top Clic Event Handler */
        $("#scrollToTop").click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, "slow");
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Instantiate new Home class */
        app.homeIndex = new HomeIndex();
        /* Initialize the Scroll To Top button */
        app.homeIndex.initialiseScrollToTopButton();
    });
}

/* common.js */
function common() {
    let self = this;
    /* Properties */
    this.promoBar = {
        promoItems: null,
        currentItem: 0,
        numberOfItems: 0,
    };
    /* Methods */
    this.initialisePromo = function() {
        /* Get all items in promo bar */
        let promoitems = $("#promo > div");
        /* Set values */
        this.promoBar.promoItems = promoItems;
        this.promoBar.numberOfItems = promoItems.length;
        /* Initiate promo loop to show next item */
        this.startDelay();
    }
    this.startDelay = function() {
        /* Wait 4 seconds then show the next message */
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.showNextPeromotionItem()
        }, 4000);
    }
    this.showNextPromoItem = function() {
        /* Fade out the current item */
        $(self.promoBar.promoItem).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function() {
            /* Increment current promo item counter */
            if (self.promoBar.currentItem >= (self.promoBar.numberOfItems - 1)) {
                /* Reset counter to zero */
                self.promoBar.currentItem = o;
            } else {
                /* Increase counter by 1 */
                self.promoBar.currentItems++;
            }
            /* Fade in the next item */
            $(self.promoBar.promoItems).eq(self.promoBar.currentItem),
                FadeIn("slow", function() {
                    /* Delay before showing next item */
                    self.startDelay();
                });
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Instantiate new Common class */
    app.common = new Common();
    /* Initialize the Promo bar */
    app.common.initialisePromo();
});
```

Comment: **What** isn't defined, though? Tangential: please indent code.

Comment: new common()   ...

Comment: Not really related to the question, but if you're starting out in 2023, I would suggest not to learn jQuery. It's not necessary anymore with modern JavaScript and typically only used in legacy projects.

Comment: @Mushroomator i wouldn't agree, jQuery is still more laconic, readable and safe than Vanilla JS. the only problem that if you work with a framework like Vue with virtual DOM, DOM manipulation isn't recommended, so jQuery could be excessive to include in a project, so Vanilla JS could be a more appropriate choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class name from `common` to `Common`:

```js
/* app.js */

var app = (function() {
  /* Properties */
  var websiteName = "PetShop";
  /* Methods */
  return {
    getWebsiteName: function() {
      return websiteName;
    }
  }
})();


/* home.js */


function HomeIndex() {
  /* Properties */
  const heightFromTop = 300;
  /* Methods */
  this.initialiseScrollToTopButton = function() {
    /* Windows Scroll Event Handler */
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      /* Show of Hide Scroll Event to Top Button based on scroll distance */
      var verticalHeight = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (verticalHeight > heightFromTop) {
        $("#scrollToTop").fadeIn();
      } else {
        $("#scrollToTop").fadeOut();
      }
    });
    /* Scroll to Top Clic Event Handler */
    $("#scrollToTop").click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, "slow");
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Instantiate new Home class */
    app.homeIndex = new HomeIndex();
    /* Initialize the Scroll To Top button */
    app.homeIndex.initialiseScrollToTopButton();
  });
}

/* common.js */

function Common() {
  let self = this;
  /* Properties */
  this.promoBar = {
    promoItems: null,
    currentItem: 0,
    numberOfItems: 0,
  };
  /* Methods */
  this.initialisePromo = function() {
    /* Get all items in promo bar */
    let promoitems = $("#promo > div");
    /* Set values */
    this.promoBar.promoItems = promoItems;
    this.promoBar.numberOfItems = promoItems.length;
    /* Initiate promo loop to show next item */
    this.startDelay();
  }
  this.startDelay = function() {
    /* Wait 4 seconds then show the next message */
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.showNextPeromotionItem()
    }, 4000);
  }
  this.showNextPromoItem = function() {
    /* Fade out the current item */
    $(self.promoBar.promoItem).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function() {
      /* Increment current promo item counter */
      if (self.promoBar.currentItem >= (self.promoBar.numberOfItems - 1)) {
        /* Reset counter to zero */
        self.promoBar.currentItem = o;
      } else {
        /* Increase counter by 1 */
        self.promoBar.currentItems++;
      }
      /* Fade in the next item */
      $(self.promoBar.promoItems).eq(self.promoBar.currentItem),
        FadeIn("slow", function() {
          /* Delay before showing next item */
          self.startDelay();
        });
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Instantiate new Common class */
  app.common = new Common();
  /* Initialize the Promo bar */
  app.common.initialisePromo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I see this issue:  jQuery.Deferred exception: promoItems is not defined ReferenceError: promoItems is not defined
    at Common.initialisePromo (https://stacksnippets.net/js:74:32)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://stacksnippets.net/js:109:14)
    at l (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0

Comment: @AndNard that's because there's no HTML provided for `let promoitems = $("#promo > div");`

Comment: Hi @AlexanderNenashev..It seems I was able to fix that one and now I see no errors in the Inspect/Console on Google Chrome...Neverthless, nothing is working Java wise

Comment: @AndNard then please accept my answer (the checkbox) so i would be rewarded with points. that's how stackoverflow works, thanks!

Comment: I did it @AlexanderNenashev and thank you, but I did not really solve the problem as Java does not work at all...I wish I had a way to show you the HTML and CSS codes